# Changing value in numericupdown in c# form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, numericupdown

The problem is that the numericupdown doesn't change types of speed for fast and slow. Basically it would speed up whether the value is positive or negative and if I take it to back to zero it will crash. I am now trying to make an if loop inside of the numericupdown for TickCounter.

Here it is:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{          
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "AAAAAAA AAAAAAA #########";            
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                TickCounterLabel.Text = "The timer has started";
                tPeriodic.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TickCounterLabel.Text = "The timer has ended";
                tPeriodic.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void TickCounter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **TickCounter.Value = TickCount;
            if (TickCount >= 0)
                tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 / Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);
            else if (TickCount <= 0)
                tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);
            else if (TickCount == 0)
                tPeriodic.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);**                          
        }

        private void tPeriodic_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            tickCount += 1;
            lTickCount.Text = tickCount.ToString();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
        }

        public int tickCount { get; set; }

        public int X { get; set; }

        private void TickCounterLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
        }

        public int TickCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Should I use another type of loop or am I just writing this wrong? When I try to change the value now it just crashes and the doesn't change at all.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished? Also, should else if (TickCount == 0) be different if I don't want to have any change at all?

Comment: Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0.
Parameter name: Interval

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to programming and to C#. I do not know how to provide the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because of divide by zero.
In the code of "TickCounter_ValueChanged", for TickCount=0, it just gets into the first "if" block and will cause the exception.

You need to use "if-else" conditions in a correct way.

```
    private void TickCounter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TickCounter.Value > 0)
            tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 / Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);

        else if (TickCounter.Value < 0)
            tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value);

        else
            tPeriodic.Interval = 1000;
    }
```

Please let me know whether it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the edit to my post masum7. That did not work. It gave an error and said: Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0.
Parameter name: Interval

Comment: Can you please complete your comment. Then it would be easier to identify what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter. Thanks for your patience with my inexperience.

Comment: Ok, so, you can modify the last block as below, just set some non-zero value.

tPeriodic.Interval = 1
\

Comment: So, you can try to set some non-zero value in last block of else:

tPeriodic.Interval = 1

Comment: ok, that got rid of the error and now the count starts and the speed will change, but it only goes fast and not slow.

Comment: Do you know what *tPeriodic.Interval = 1;* does? It sets the timer to 1msec so in theory(the timer accuracy can not go below 10msec) you are calling *lTickCount.Text = tickCount.ToString();* 1000 times a second.

Comment: Okay, I have modified again. I think it is unnecessary to set TickCounter.Value from the variable TickCount.

Comment: So it should be set to 1000 to get the normal rate of counting seconds?

Comment: Check the last version. I have set 1000 and also I find it quite unnecessary to use TickCount. You should directly use TickCounter.Value because in your code, TickCount never decreases below zero

Comment: masum7, that produced the same results as the last edit. It seems that only part of the if loop that is being used in the program is the else tPeriodic.Interval = 1;, which I changed to 1000 and got the normal second count. The thing is that I would like for the program to speed up and slow down the count, which is why I tried to make the loop. if I use  tPeriodic.Interval = 1000 / Convert.ToInt32(TickCounter.Value * TickCounter.Value); by itself then it works, but only one way, which is why I wanted to use negative numbers as the rate of the count slowing and have 0 be a normal second.

Comment: Yes I did. I already got what my teacher assigned me to do. I was just trying to go beyond the assignment.